# SharpSvn creating repository on a SVN server via http(s)

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

How do I create a repository on a Svn Apache server using SharpSvn library given a valid credential?

i.e. creating a repository through http(s) instead of through filesystem.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I'm not making myself clear.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to create a new repository is through `svnadmin create`.